# How to enable Vibrate on call connect?

Tags: calls, 5.1-lollipop, vibration

I am using Android lollipop 5.1.1 on Google Nexus 5. I used to have a feature on Nokia feature phone, which would vibrate the phone when the person at other end picks up the call. I want this kind of feature on Nexus 5. I have no root. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** → **Sounds**,  scroll to bottom and tap **Also Vibrate For Calls**.

Comment: I noticed that it only vibrates when I receive call, not when someone picks up my call.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure this is possible without root. You may be able to use a third party app but there is no "built-in" feature like this